# Function to map unit circle to halfway points

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I couldn't find a previous question covering this but I also find that it's difficult to explain the exact problem so my apologies if this is a duplicate.

I am trying to find the function to map whole-number degrees of a unit circle $h(x)$ to discrete bifurcations for that given rotation $H(x)$. For every rotation, only two points on the circle can be returned. The result should be bound to the unit circle ( i.e. $0° <= H(x) < 360°$ )

The application of this is selecting colors on a color circle via a hue value given in degrees. For a linear dataset of whole numbers, each one maps to a hue value that is furthest from its neighbors while attempting to maintain uniqueness in the set (until we run out of discrete colors, then it repeats). So if 0 is red, then 1 is light blue, 2 is purple, 3 is green... and so on.

To give an idea of the desired mapping, here are the values I am expecting:

| $x$ | $H(x)$ |
| --- | --- |
| $-1°$ | $-180°$ |
| $0°$ | $0°$ |
| $1°$ | $180°$ |
| $2°$ | $90°$ |
| $3°$ | $270°$ |
| $4°$ | $45°$ |
| $5°$ | $225°$ |
| $6°$ | $135°$ |
| $7°$ | $315°$ |
| $8°$ | $22°$ (the end-value will be floored) |
| $8°$ | $202°$ (the end-value will be floored) |

Direct mapping (without the "bifurcation shifting"): $h(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor \bmod 360$

I have componentized operations for the desired formula as follows:

Rotations: $ \phi(x) = \lfloor \frac{x}{360} \rfloor $

'Offset': $ o(x) = \frac{180}{2^{\lvert\phi(x)\rvert}} $

'Shifted' Value: $ s(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor 180 $

Using the above, here is my closest attempt:
$H(x)= (s(x) + o(s(x))) \bmod 360$

The problem appears to be that it doesn't bifurcate the whole circle on each rotation and continues to hone in on the offsets after $0°$ and $180°$. Feels close yet so far away.

Here are some javascript versions of the above functions I have been using to test while trying to work this out:

```
h = (x) => x % 360
p = (x) => Math.floor(x / 360)
o = (x) => 180 / Math.pow(2, Math.abs(p(x)))
s = (x) => (Math.floor(x) * 180)
H = (x) => (s(x)+o(s(x))) % 360

// Then test using H(x)
```

Comment: Inching closer, here is a codepen that I am using to work through this: https://codepen.io/daerogami/pen/poNbLKy?editors=0010

Comment: Although it's irrelevant to the maths of your question, hues in HSL aren't very uniform: the yellow-green parts take up a large chunk of the circle. Also saturation and lightness are only roughly correlated with the perceived colour richness and brightness. Wikipedia has more info on this. For further info, do a search on "perceptually uniform color spaces"; here's a relevant page with some JavaScript: https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/perceptually-uniform-color-spaces/

Comment: As for your mathematical problem, I suggest you use [Farey sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) instead of your binary scheme. As well as a more uniform colour space than HSL. ;)

Comment: TIL about Farey sequences. Thank you! Will investigate this as a solution but will still work towards finding the above function either way.